# How to get exact phrase followed by particular word in json bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I've got such a column named X and I need to get the phase after word "name"

Here is an example of one row of json type:

`{"id":"5df8c913e069a09e0467179e","name":"Contacts in description","vote":"REFUSE","notice":{"text":"Contacts or URLs in description are not allowed on JamesEdition","severity":"PROBLEM"},"wordHighlighting":[{"words":[{"word":"yes","regex":"/^yes$/"}],"variableName":"$text.hasUrl"}]}`

So the result I need in this case is: `Contacts in description`
Also sometimes there are several `name` in one string: I need to grab them all

Thanks a lot for attention!

Comment: you mentioned "sometimes there are several name in one string: I need to grab them all" - provide example and expected output!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks a lot for your comment! I would like two have two (or more) seperate columns with "after "name"" phrases

Comment: you should update your question with good example of input and expected output!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions):

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"id":"5df8c913e069a09e0467179e","name":"Contacts in description","vote":"REFUSE","notice":{"text":"Contacts or URLs in description are not allowed on JamesEdition","severity":"PROBLEM"},"wordHighlighting":[{"words":[{"word":"yes","regex":"/^yes$/"}],"variableName":"$text.hasUrl"}]}', '$.name')
```

[image]